# Laravel 4 Validation is Broken

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4

A simple date format mm/dd/yyyy validation is all I need...

```
$rules = array(
    'renewal_date' =>  array('required', 'date_format:?')
    );
```

What do I set the date format to? The Laravel documentation could be so much better.

Comment: Can you post the code that calls the Validator -- it's possible the error is there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Workaround:

```
'renewal_date' => array('required', 'date_format:m/d/Y', 'regex:/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}/')
```

Answer (score 12):

Documentation is pretty clear to me, you should use

**date_format:format**

"The field under validation must match the format defined according to the **date_parse_from_format** PHP function."

Looking at it: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php, I see you can do something like this:

```
$rules = array(
    'renewal_date' =>  array('required', 'date_format:"m/d/Y"')
    );
```

This is pure PHP test for it:

```
print_r(date_parse_from_format("m/d/Y", "04/01/2013"));
```

You can also do it manually in Laravel to test:

```
$v = Validator::make(['date' => '09/26/13'], ['date' => 'date_format:"m/d/Y"']);
var_dump( $v->passes() );
```

To me it's printing

**boolean true**

Comment: 'renewal_date' =>  array('required', 'date_format:"m/d/Y"') does not work

Comment: Added a standalone test so you can see if it's Laravel or anything else in your code.

Comment: There is indeed a problem with it, some warnings are not being processed. Just posted an issue on github: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/issues/2317.

Comment: Workaround: 'renewal_date' => array('required', 'date_format:m/d/Y', 'regex:/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}/')

Comment: @AntonioCarlosRibeiro - How do you explain this? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/215e5a5fa045167d9e2b8e1d9ac7f26648b3cb30

Comment: I can`t see anything wrong. That's the normal behaviour of this function.

Comment: Sorry, it's a PHP bug, just answered it on github.

Answer (score 6):

I got a similar problem, but with a d/m/Y date format.
In my case, the problem was that I defined both "date" and "date_format" rules for the same field:

```
public static $rules = array(
    'birthday' => 'required|date|date_format:"d/m/Y"',
    ...
```

The solution is to remove the "date" validator: **you must not use both**. Like this:

```
public static $rules = array(
    'birthday' => 'required|date_format:"d/m/Y"',
    ...
```

after that, all is well.

Answer (score 1):

You should use with `double quote` like `"Y-m-d H:i:s"`

```
$rules = array(
    'renewal_date' =>  array('required', 'date_format:"m/d/Y"')
                                                      ^     ^ this ones
);
```

**Discussion about this issue on GitHub:** https://github.com/laravel/laravel/pull/1192

Comment: 'renewal_date' =>  array('required', 'date_format:"m/d/Y"') still does not work.

Comment: @suncoastkid I guess syntax is wrong. Try without `required` like `$rules = array('renewal_date' => 'date_format:"m/d/Y"');`

Comment: Thanks but that still doesn't work... this is so frustrating. This should be simple.

Answer (score 0):

date_format didn't work for me , so I did this custom validation

```
Validator::extend('customdate', function($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
  $parsed_date = date_parse_from_format ( "Y-m-d" , $value);
  $year = $parsed_date['year'];
  $month = $parsed_date['month'];
  $month = $month <= 9 ? "0" . $month : $month;
  $day = $parsed_date['day'];
  $day = $day <= 9 ? "0" . $day : $day;
  return checkdate($month, $day, $year);
});

$validation = Validator::make(
  array('date' => $num),
  array('date' => 'customdate')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the PHP `date_parse_from_format` (Laravel 4):

```
'birthday' => 'date_format:m/d/Y'
```

Your validation message will also use `"m/d/Y"` which the average user will not understand.
*The birthday does not match the format m/d/Y*

Recommend customizing your message for this invalid response.
*The birthday does not match the format mm/dd/yyyy*

Answer (score 0):

Source : Click [Here](http://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/validation-and-behavior-of-date-date-format-before-and-after-rules)

**You can use like**

```
$rules = [
    'start_date'        => 'date_format:d/m/Y|after:tomorrow',
    'end_date'          => 'date_format:d/m/Y|after:start_date',
];
```