# Laravel date validation failing to require 4 digit year

Tags: validation, date, laravel-4

I'm kind of puzzled at the results I'm getting from a Laravel date validation.  The rule in question is:

```
'date_of_birth'=>array('required', 'date_format:n/j/Y')
```

What I'm finding is that if somebody enters 10/12/13, it passes validation, and gets stored as 10/12/0013.  Obviously, that's not good.  Is there any way of getting validation to demand a four-digit year?  I assumed that's what the Y in the format would do.

Comment: I can reproduce this (Laravel 4.2.11, PHP 5.5). As discussed in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852536/laravel-4-validation-is-broken), it seems to be a PHP (not Laravel) specific bug. But you can work around it: `array('required', 'date_format:n/j/Y', 'regex:/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}/')`

Comment: Darn, I tried searching for other questions on the topic, but that one didn't come up.  I don't know regex, so as a partial fix I added `after:01-01-1900', which would catch this error and a variety of fatfingerings.  Your answer is the right one, though.  If you want to add it as a separate response I'd be happy to mark you correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Posting my comment as an answer*

**Note:** This is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852536/laravel-4-validation-is-broken) and the general discussion there. The workaround was posted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852536/laravel-4-validation-is-broken#21607400) on the above mentioned question. The PHP bug is mentioned in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852536/laravel-4-validation-is-broken#comment27826838_18852638). So I do not take any credit for this solution.

**The Answer:** This seems to be a bug in PHP's function [date_parse_from_format()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php). You can work around it by specifying stricter rules with a regex expression:

```
array('required', 'date_format:n/j/Y', 'regex:/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}/')
```

It may look complicated at first if you're not familiar with regex, but if you break it apart, it's just says:

`[0-9]{2}` = there must be 2 subsequent digits, each between 0 and 9.

`[0-9]{4}` = there must be 4 subsequent digits, each between 0 and 9.

`\/` = there must be a slash. It's escaped by the backslash.

**BUT:** Personally, I do not quite like this solution. Even though it ensures a four-digit year, a date like '99/99/9999' would still pass.

This is **not** the case with your `after:01-01-1900` workaround. So, even though it's not being used as intended, I would still go with

```
'date_of_birth'=>array('required', 'date_format:"n/j/Y"', 'after:01-01-1900')
```

(or maybe adjust the regex a little...).

One thing to keep in mind: It works, but I'm not quite sure why. The underlying PHP function on the after-filter is [DateTime::createFromFormat()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('n/j/Y', '99/99/9999');
```

gives me a date of '10007-06-07', which should actually be after '01-01-1900', but the validator fails - maybe because of the comparison of the two dates, maybe because of the invalid values. And I have no idea how it was calculated. It's somewhat unpredictable behaviour, so handle with caution :)

*If it's stupid but it works, it isn't stupid.* - Murphy's law

Comment: Is it really "a bug"? There **was** a year 13 AD.

Comment: @ceejayoz Sure, but you pass a `Y` to the function which says that you want to display the year with 4 digits. It's not about if the year is valid, it's about how it's passed / displayed, and the validator should make sure that you pass 13 AD as 0013 and not just 13.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful response, and nice explanation of the regexp as well.

Comment: Coming back to this a year and a half later, I thought I'd add that changing the {2} to {1,2} in the regex will allow for 1 or 2 digit day and month values for ease of data entry.  The 4 digit year was the biggie.